# Reading deeper into firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My aim is to display the names of the tournaments in a list view.

This is what my database looks like:
[image]

The code that I use to populate my list view is as follows:

```
//list view to be populated with tournament data
    final ListView tournamentListView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    //finding and setting the empty view in the listView when the list has 0 items
    View emptyView = findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    tournamentListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);

    final ArrayList<String> tournamentNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    DatabaseReference tournamentRef = mDatabase.child("Tournaments");
    tournamentRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot tournamentIds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                for (DataSnapshot tournament : tournamentIds.getChildren()) {
                    TournamentInformation tournamentInformation = new TournamentInformation();
                    tournamentInformation.setTournamentName(tournament.getValue(TournamentInformation.class).getTournamentName());
                    tournamentNamesList.add(tournamentInformation.getTournamentName());
                    Log.d("Main Activity", tournamentInformation.getTournamentName());
                }
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,tournamentNamesList);
            tournamentListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My app crashes on startup, and I get the following message in the logcat:

> Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed
>
> A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db.18' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
>
> A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

I don't know what these errors mean, primarily because I'm not using SQLite.

Does anyone know what's going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While Firebase does use SQLite internally for its disk persistence, the error message seems unrelated to that. Is there any other error message/stack trace that points to something in the code you shared?

Comment: why the second loop ? your data does not reflect the need of the second loop

Comment: sorry, my understanding of snapshots wasn't right.. i fixed that bit, but there isn't any difference - the app still crashes with the same messages in logcat @thunder413

Comment: Not seeing anything wrong with the rest of the code can you post the full stack trace

Comment: Got it to work.. I just cleaned and rebuilt the project. Thanks! @thunder413